# Creation of nginx pod does not pull image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx, kubectl, minikube

Having installed minikube, docker desktop etc. I try to create my pod like:

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx
```

, so it would be pulled from DockerHub by default, to my understanding.

Minikube returns success:

```
> minikube status
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

But `kubectl get pods` does not:

```
> kubectl get pods
NAME    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
nginx   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          33s
```

And more info I got by `kubectl describe pod nginx`:

```
> kubectl describe pod nginx
...
Status:           Pending
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ErrImagePull
      Ready:          False
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
...
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  76s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx to minikube
  Warning  Failed     55s                kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 172.23.160.1:53: read udp 172.23.164.186:40603->172.23.160.1:53: i/o timeout
  Normal   Pulling    43s (x2 over 75s)  kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
  Warning  Failed     23s (x2 over 55s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     23s                kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 172.23.160.1:53: read udp 172.23.164.186:48071->172.23.160.1:53: i/o timeout
  Normal   BackOff    12s (x2 over 54s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "nginx"
  Warning  Failed     12s (x2 over 54s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

**Why this image could not be pulled? Where to look for the reason?**

I turned off Windows Firewall for a moment to be sure.

I tried `docker pull nginx` and got success:

```
> docker pull nginx
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
docker.io/library/nginx:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your DNS config using google dns 8.8.8.8:

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

If you're using your own local DNS server, you can also try to change your Docker config by modifying your docker daemon.json file, and then restart the service:

```
sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
# { "dns" : [ "8.8.4.4" , "8.8.8.8" ] } 

sudo systemctl docker restart
```